# unable to convert byte[] to image

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve a picture stored in MS SQL Server database. The type of the column is image. My code is:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, con);
    cmd.CommandText = "select Picture from Person";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dataReader.Read();

    byte[] image = new byte[10000];
    long len = dataReader.GetBytes(0, 0, image, 0, 10000);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image))
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I am continuously getting `ArgumentException` as *Parameter is not valid* when I set the pictureBox1.Image property. I tried all the available solutions on the Internet but all in vain.

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144870/get-image-from-mysql-database-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You are always using a `10000` byte array even if the image is smaller (or larger). Don't manually create the `byte[]`, the `DataReader` can provide the entire byte array if you ask for it.

```
byte[] image = reader.GetFieldValue<byte[]>(0);
```

If you are not using .NET 4.5 you can just ask for the field and cast it manually.

```
byte[] image = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0);
```

However the fact that you are only using the first column from the first row you don't need a `DataReader` at all, just use `ExecuteScalar()` instead. (I also am cleaning up your code to use proper `using` statements and switched your `ex.Message` to `ex.ToString()` to provide more info in the error dialog).

```
try
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, con))
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Picture from Person";
        con.Open();

        byte[] image = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, con);
cmd.CommandText = "select Picture from Person";
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
byte[] image = new byte[10000];
long len = dataReader.GetBytes(0, 0, image, 0, 10000);
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(image))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mStream);
}
```

Comment: Other than removing the `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` I don't see any changes to the code (Which BTW does not change the progam at all, the stream was already at position 0 so the seek actually did not move it at all). Also that still does not fix the problem, you don't try to read images larger than `10000` and you send in potentially extra uninitialized bytes to `MemoryStream`